# Is there a way to send or trigger keystrokes in Cypress on a webpage?

Tags: selenium, cypress, e2e-testing

what I am trying to do is that when I navigate to a certain page there I need to press certain key from the keyboard i.e. alphabets to perform an action on the webpage.

The scenario is:

1- Navigate to webpage
2- Press a specific alphabet from the keyboard
3- Page performs an action when this alphabet is pressed from the keyboard

Currently, I am not sure how can I achieve this with Cypress normally we can type in the input box etc but I just want to simulate the keypress on the webpage. Is there a way to do this with the help of trigger function? if so then how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `cy.get('selecor').type('A')` ?

Comment: Actually I don't want to type into an input box, what I am trying to do is for example, Let say I am on a webpage and there is a button , I can click on this button to perform an action or I can use the keyboard to press a key (allocated to that button in the web application) from the keyboard to perform that action. I want to test the same thing, that somehow I can trigger keystroke and check if the button performed the action.

Comment: Can you share your webpage or a similar example or HTML code of your element?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send the key strokes to in cypress

```
cy.get('input').type('{shift}{alt}Q')
cy.get('input').type('{enter}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/46912/how-to-simulate-a-simple-keypress-in-cypress

Also, check out the documentation for [Trigger](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger) in cypress. Check out recipes too. maybe you'll find something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's the [official documentation](https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions#type) by Cypress. Just use the key modifiers in the .type() method:

```
.type('{meta}{command}{cmd}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to get a specific element in your DOM, and assuming your page either capture the event or focus the right element in the first place then you can try this :

```
cy.get('body').type('{enter}')
```

This will get the whole page and press the Enter key.
You can't just have `cy.type('{enter}')` because it needs to be chained of an element. When you think about it, as a human, it's like hitting the key without having chrome focused.